# How to make a 3D model from video clips?

Tags: video, image-processing, 3d, video-processing, 3d-modelling

I am beginner of this area. And I am looking for solutions to make a 3D model from video clips? For now, I only focus on 3D head model.

Is there any tool/paper that I can refer to?

Thanks.

Comment: have you search before asking here ? 3D reconstruction is a widely spread topic

Comment: you can read about Structure from motion (SFM).

Comment: Because you can already make a 3d head model from a few still photos? If not maybe start there for basics. What programming language are you using? Have you handled any 2D pixel edge detection? Any 3D polygon calculations? Any 3d programming? These details are missing from your question.

Comment: My final aim is to create a 3d model which can be imported into 3d software, such as 3dMAX, then after certain modification, print it out using 3d printer.